# Momentjs return wrong date after minutes manipulation

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, date, momentjs

In my php application I set the italian timezone like this way:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
```

the string above is located in my `config.php` file, the core of the app. Anyway, from the backend I using `momentjs` with `CodeIgniter` framework. When a user select a date from the properly input set this result:

[image]

Now I get the value from this input like this:

```
var end_date_temp = Date.parse($('#end-datetime').val());
```

And the initial result is wrong:

> Tue Mar 01 2016 11:03:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)

The rest of code is:

```
var end_date = moment(end_date_temp).add(serviceDuration, 'minutes').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
$('#end-datetime').val(end_date);
```

NB: I also tried to set `moment.locale('it')` but the same result appear, in my javascript libraries I've the italian timezone of momentjs. What is wrong?

UPDATE Code:

```
var end_date_temp = moment($('#end-datetime').val())._i;
var end_date = moment(moment(end_date_temp).add(serviceDuration, 'minutes')).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
$('#end-datetime').val(end_date);
```

Comment: Do *not* use the `_i` field, nor any other fields with the `_` prefix.  They are not meant for external consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// parse the input string to a moment object, **specifying the input format**
var end_date = moment($('#end-datetime').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');

// manipulate it as desired
end_date.add(serviceDuration, 'minutes');

// format it to the specified output format, and assign the result back to your field
$('#end-datetime').val(end_date.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
```

You can do this in one line of code if you like.

```
$('#end-datetime').val(moment($('#end-datetime').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').add(serviceDuration, 'minutes').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
```

The locale setting isn't important with this particular bit of code, because you don't use any locale-specific functions or format specifiers

Comment: Great solution Matt, now I feel like the last image of dev life: 
http://martinvalasek.com/blog/pictures-from-a-developers-life-part-2
have a nice day, and happy new year!

Comment: Thanks.  You as well!

Comment: @Dillinger So I post the exact same thing not chewing for you and it's not a valid answer?

Comment: @ShanShan I did't say that's not a valid answer, but for my case it didn't work, however other users may find it better that my and Matt answers. I'm sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

momentjs is using the american date format (MM/DD/YYYY), enforce a format to get the right date:

```js
var input = '03/01/2016 11:00';
var date = moment(input, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');

document.write(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already use .format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'); but the final date is incorrect as I explained above..

Comment: `format()` is for returning a date as a string. To correctly parse the input, you have to put the format as second parameter of `moment()`.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of attempts, I fixed in my timezone (italian) like so:

```
moment.locale('it');

var end_date_temp = moment($('#end-datetime').val()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
var end_date = moment(end_date_temp).add(30, 'minutes');
$('#end-datetime').val(moment(moment(end_date).toDate()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
```

I declared the `.locale` as `it`, in the next time I formatted the time returned from the input text in my timezone as well. I've manipulated the date with the `.add` method, for do this I've create another instance of momentjs object. At the end I pass the value from the input, re-formatted the date again in my timezone format 'cause in the manipulation I lose the previous formatting. The final result is what I wanted. Hope this help, anyway, if someone find a solution more optimized than my I'll be happy to see.

Comment: You're still confusing the input format with the output format and parsing/converting multiple times unnecessarily.  I'll post a better version of this in a separate answer.

Comment: [See my answer for the correct implementation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575111/momentjs-return-wrong-date-after-minutes-manipulation/34580386#34580386)